# Subtract from an array of char a number of characters

Tags: c, ubuntu, file-io

I can't seem to work it out. I am using a .c code that opens a file and reads each line. I would like to save in char*substr 4 characters from the line 9 inside the txt file. The line 5 contains
name=Me She; I would like to have in char*substr just Meli.Need help. THX
Here is the c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *fp;
  char str[128];
char str1[128];

  if((fp = fopen("/home/folder/file.txt", "r"))==NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open file.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

int lin=0;
  while(!feof(fp)) {
    if(fgets(str, 126, fp)) 
        printf("%s", str);
        if (lin==8)
        {
            char *c= (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(str)+1);

            c= strndup(str, strlen(str)-5);?? not working?!!!
            printf("d is:",c);
        }

        lin=lin+1;
  }

  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If its the ninth line in the file you require then change `if (lin==9)` to `if (lin==8)` as `lin` is initialised to `0`.

Comment: Please take more care over your questions, with fewer typos and more fully-spelt-out words.

Comment: make sure that a line is not too long if you use `fgets()`, [example](http://ideone.com/aNz32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your printf is wrong. change it to `printf("d is %s\n",c);`.

By the way, `strdup` allocate the memory needed, so you don't have to allocate it yourself. (In fact, you have a memory leak).

Comment: please hellp:) Can you correct my post? i don't know how to solve this. thx

Comment: Just change the `printf` like I said, and remove the `malloc` line.

Comment: how to extract just 4 characters from position 3 for example?

Comment: `strndup(str+2,4);` (The 2 is chars to skip. the 4 is for copy 4 chars)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `malloc()` and then directly overwriting its result with that of calling `strndup()`, this leaks memory.

Also, the logic in the `strndup()` call looks wrong. If you want to skip the first 5 characters, you should have `str + 5`.

If you have `strdup()`, use:

```
    if (lin==9)
    {
       char *name = strdup(str + 5);
       printf("name is: '%s'\n", name != NULL ? name : "(failed)");
    }
```

Then you should probably `break` out of the loop. Also note that the pointer `name` goes out of scope, so it's not available to code outside the loop for instance.

Comment: He want to skip the `last` 5 chars.

Comment: I want to ship the first 4 characters and take just 4. My example was: name=Me SHelila... I WAnt to take just me. After that i also want to copy name in char *concat using strcpy(concat,name);

Comment: in my case it prints the number of characters I want + the whole line.Why?